# disabling focus after closing modal in React component

Tags: reactjs, focus

In the React app I'm working on, a cancel button is located at the bottom of a page. When a user clicks on the button, a confirmation modal appears, and once the user confirms, a progress spinner appears at the top of the page, and soon after the browser exits the react app onto a different html page. However, the progress spinner is cut off from view because immediately after closing the modal, the browser scrolls all the way down back to the cancel button.

I know for accessibility reasons you generally *want* to focus on the launching element after closing a modal, but in this instance I want to prevent the browser from focusing back on the cancel button and instead stay on the top of the page where the spinner renders. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using React JS refs to focus the element you want to focus ? Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs)

Comment: Yes, I just used the example in that link to insert an input in the top of my page with a ref, and inside my cancel function called on a function to focus on it. It does apparently focus on it for a millisecond but then scrolls down to the bottom. Looks like I need to short circuit the default focus behavior from happening in the first place. Guessing that will involve going in the code for the modal's onHide callback function.